# Selenium right clicks at (0,0) instead of element but only after first loop

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Note: Using chrome 76, a new tab opens for every file

I have to download a lot of files, and I have to right-click and save link as. This works for the first file, but for subsequent files it right clicks at (0,0).

The download link only appears after clicking a download button. I have tried using implicit and explicit waits, however, this doesn't seem to be the problem as the first file works fine. I have used the element.location property to check the location right before the click however it is the same whether it clicks in the right spot or not.

Python

```py
downloadButton.click()
#have tried time.sleep here doesn't work
downloadLink = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, 'somepath'))
)
print(str(downloadLink.location)) #shows same correct location every time
actionChains.context_click(downloadLink).perform()
time.sleep(.1)
for i in range(4):
    keyboard.send('down')
keyboard.send('enter')
time.sleep(1)
keyboard.send('enter')
```

Some HTML after the dl button has been clicked, can provide more if necessary

```html
<div class="tab-content transparent no-padding-top margin-top">
                        <div class="tab-pane active" id="file">
                            <div data-bind="with: resource" class="form-horizontal form-panel">                                
                                <div class="form-group" data-bind="slideVisible: downloadedUrl() != ''" style="display: block;">
                                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Download Link</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                                        <div class="bg-info padding">
                                            <h4>Download version: <span data-bind="text: downloadName">Current Version</span></h4>
                                            Click the link below to download this file.
                                            <b>NOTE:</b> for larger files it may take a short time for the download to start.
                                            <br>
                                            <br>
                                            <a style="word-break: break-all;" target="_blank" data-bind="attr: { href: downloadedUrl }, text: downloadedUrl" href="link">link</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

hopefully that is somewhat formatted I copy-pasted from chrome console

Expected to right-click on the link element, clicks in the top left corner (0,0) instead

Comment: Make sure your xpath is looking at the active tab `//div[@class='tab-pane active']//label[.='Download Link']`. Seems to be your xpath is pointing to the inactive tab.

Comment: @supputuri I tried //div[@class="tab-pane active"]//*[@id="file"]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/a as the xpath instead of //*[@id="file"]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/a and it timed out, just to note I use this: driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1]) when the new tab opens and close the tab using ctrl+w when done

Comment: ` //div[@class="tab-pane active"]//*[@id="file"]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/a` is this xpath working in the devtools? If yes, then use `driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])` to access the latest tab. `-1` will point to the latest tab. And you can use driver.close to close the tab instead of  ctrl+w. Make sure you switch to default/parent window once you closed the tab.

Comment: @supputuri that xpath is not showing up in devtools, tried using the -1 as well, I do switch back to parent once tab is closed

Comment: sorry, did not get `not showing up in devtools`. Do you mean there are no matching elements on the page with the xpath when you tried in devtools?

Comment: @supputuri yes, I crtl+f'd the xpath in devtools

Comment: `//div[@class="tab-pane active"][@id="file"]//a` is the xpath that you should use.

Comment: @supputuri that path worked but it still clicks in the top left after the first file

Comment: Ok, can you tell me how many elements matched that xpath on the page. And if you have more than 1 element, then you can see there will be some attribute difference between them/ their ancestor.

Comment: @supputuri there are 17 matches, and I'm not entirely sure what you meant by the second part but there are different attributes than the element I am trying to target

Comment: Ok, Can you try with this xpath `//div[@class="tab-pane active"][@id="file"]//div[@style='display: block;']//a` this should select the links which are visible, filtering out the links with 0,0 coordinates.

Comment: @supputuri still happening, the most confusing part is that the first one works fine but afterwards it breaks, maybe the website is just dumb and I'll have to find another way of doing it

Comment: OK. Is that  a public url?

Comment: @supputuri No sorry, I'll probably just open the link and use the download button there, didn't want to in order to save time but oh well